# How to get a Tools.Excel.Worksheet from an Interop.Excel.Worksheet in a standalone application?

Tags: excel, vsto, office-interop, excel-interop

I have a class library (that can be seen as a stand-alone application for this purpose) that does this:

- Creates a new excel application
- Creates a new sheet
- Populates the sheet
- Needs to add controls to the sheet with events (c# events, not willing to use VBA or text scripts)

My library cannot have another project type, nor can it be a VSTO addin (because this library is already an addin for another application not related with Office, this I cannot change)

Nevertheless, I noticed that I can reference the `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.dll` library and access its types which exposes the control methods I want to explore.

So, the questions are:

- **How can I get a `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet` from a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet` object?**

From the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/extending-word-documents-and-excel-workbooks-in-vsto-add-ins-at-run-time?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2022), I see that they suggest to use `Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(nativeWorkbook)`. The problem is: my application is not a VSTO add-in and I do not have a `Globals` variable in my project.

- **Is there a way to access the `Globals` class/variable from a standalone application?**
- **Is there a way to create a `Globals` instance from `Microsoft.Office.Interop` somehow?**

Unfortunately, `Factory` is not a class that I can instanciate, it's just an interface

- **Is it possible  to create an intance of `Factory` in a standalone application?**

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The `Globals` namespace makes sense only for VSTO based add-ins. Read more about that in the [Global access to objects in Office projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/global-access-to-objects-in-office-projects?view=vs-2022) article.